# installing gems in specified path ignores global gems

Tags: rubygems, bundler

I have a problem with installing gems in user folder. I'm using rbenv and my *gem env* contains two gem paths (global and user specific):

```
GEM PATHS:
 - /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
 - /home/my-user/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
```

I don't have write permission for global path so I have to use *.gem/ruby/2.2.0* path in my users directory.

But I would also like to use gems already installed under the global path without reinstalling them in user path again.

If I use option *--path* on bundle install, bundler will automatically add option *--disable-shared-gems* so it will ignore gems already installed.

I know that you can use *--user-install* option when you're installing gems with `gem` command but it's ignored by bundler.

Is there any way to do it with bundler?